# Send different email to CCN user PHP MAILER

Tags: php, phpmailer

I Use php mailer to send emails. 
Currently the system sends the e-mail to a user who types in his e-mail and a copy of the same e-mail arrives at the CCN.

I would like to send to the CCN an email with different content and not the same one.

Now my code is this:

```
require 'PHPMailer_5.2.0/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                     
$mail->Host = 'smtp.smtp.com';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'admin@admin.it';                
$mail->Password = 'XXXXXX';                         
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
$mail->Port = 587;                                   

$mail->setFrom('admin@admin.it', 'Name Surname'); 
$mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);    
$mail->AddBCC("info@admin.com"); 

$mail->isHTML(true);  

$mail->Subject = 'Report Questionario PugliaParadise';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the body message';

$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo '<div id="successo-email">Grazie! Il tuo report &egrave; stato inviato 
correttamente!</div>';
echo '</div>';*/
 }
```

I would like the user info@admin.com to receive an email with a different content in CCN.

Thanks

Comment: And what have you tried so far? It should not be too hard to swap the content before sending the mail to another recipient

Comment: You’re using an ancient version of PHPMailer that is buggy and vulnerable to attack. Upgrade it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear Recipient and resend again

```
require 'PHPMailer_5.2.0/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                     
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.smtp.com';  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
    $mail->Username = 'admin@admin.it';                
    $mail->Password = 'XXXXXX';                         
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
    $mail->Port = 587;                                   

    $mail->setFrom('admin@admin.it', 'Name Surname'); 
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);    

    $mail->isHTML(true);  

    $mail->Subject = 'Report';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the body message';

    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    $mail->Send();


$mail->ClearAllRecipients();

    $mail->Body    = 'This is the body message 2';

$mail->AddAddress("info@admin.com");

    if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo '<div id="successo-email">Grazie! Il tuo report &egrave; stato inviato 
    correttamente!</div>';
    echo '</div>';*/
     }
```